# Finding words with doubled letters in HTML text with a regexp

Tags: regex, perl, tags

How would I write regular expression that finds all words with doubled letters in a document?

By doubled letters I mean: "s in progress", "d and s in address", "o in tool" and so on. I want to match these words inside the `<body>` part of an HTML document ?

Below is a bit of code that shows what I am trying to do:

```
while (<>){
    if (/<body(.*)>/ .. /<\/body>/){
        foreach ($_){
        print $_ =~ /\b\w{0,10}(\w)\1\w{0,10}\b/;
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an obvious task, first off because parsing html with regex is hazardous. With all the disclaimers about doing so, here's a regex for the job:

```
(?s)(?:<body>|\G)(?:.(?!</body>))*?\K\b\w*(\w)\1\w*\b
```

See [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/nR2aE9).

In Perl:

```
@result = $subject =~ m%(?s)(?:<body>|\G)(?:.(?!</body>))*?\K\b\w*(\w)\1\w*\b%g;
```

- `(?s)` allows the dot to match newlines
- `(?:<body>|\G)` matches `<body>` or the ending position of the previous match
- `(?:.(?!</body>))*?` lazily matches chars that are not followed by the closing `</body>` tag
- `\K` tells the engine to drop what had been matched so far from the returned match
- `\b\w*(\w)\1\w*\b` matches a word (without `\b` boundaries) made of some optional chars `\w*` then one captured char `(\w)` immediately followed by itself as referenced by the Group 1 captured `\1` and more optional chars `\w*`

If you only want to allow letters (no digits and underscores), replace all the `\w` with `[a-z]` and replace `(?s)` with `(?is)` to make it case-insensitive.

Comment: Please don't encourage others to parse markup languages using a regular expression. Once you think you have it right it will fail a week, a month, a year later, or after the author has left employment, leaving legacy code that others will curse you for forever

Comment: @Borodin You're right. I wasn't thinking that `first off because parsing html with regex is hazardous. With all the disclaimers about doing so` was an encouragement. :) In my view there's a time for everything, and if you're a kid starting out and tinkering, then tinkering with regex is interesting and worthwhile, and you won't listen to warnings... And if you're a pro developer, you know to listen to warnings.

Comment: @zx81: That is wrong-thinking, and if you are going to explain the use of regexes to process HTML then you should at least warn that it really isn't the way to do things properly. Perhaps if HTML parsers were difficult to use I may agree with you, but your proposal is a ridiculous and unnecessary regex solution to a problem that is simple and straightforward using a parser. See my own answer

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example solution that uses [`HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder%3a%3aXPath). It finds all text nodes in the HTML within the `<body>` element, splits them into "words" (using your definition of `\w+`) and prints those that contain duplicate characters.

Note that text nodes include the JavaScript code inside `<script>` tags.

I hope you can see just how easy it is to use a real HTML parser. Several others are available if you're not comfortable with `XPath`. But please don't struggle with regular expressions to create something that is difficult to write and likely to break at any moment

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_url('http://www.perl.org/');

my @body_text = $tree->findvalues('/html/body//text()');

for my $word (map /\w+/g, @body_text) {
  say $word if $word =~ /(.)\1/;
}
```

**output**

```
Programming
www
Community
000
programming
free
books
000
community
Community
community
300
support
discussion
000
offer
opportunities
programming
discussion
collaboration
Hook
Zilla
Zilla
33
Zilla
Moos
BitTorrent
300
Current
Community
Need
look
Toolkit
need
www
2002
_setAccount
50555
https
https
ssl
http
www
google
setAttribute
appendChild
googleTranslateElementInit
google
50555
google_translate_element
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Mojo::DOM`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo%3a%3aDOM) for parsing HTML.

The following will easily do exactly what you mean without picking up additional values that are inside tag attributes or such:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Mojo::DOM;

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new(do {local $/; <DATA>});

for my $body ($dom->find('body')->each) {
    my $text = $body->all_text();
    for my $word ($text =~ m{\w+}g) {
        print "$word\n" if $word =~ /(.)\1/;
    }
}

__DATA__
<html>
<head>
<title>Dooble, but not me</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>I'm a heeder</h1>
<p style="color: reed">I have more woods to find in heer.  How many wrrds can I misspell?  Plentee without even trying</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Outputs:

```
heeder
woods
heer
wrrds
misspell
Plentee
```

For a helpful 8 minute introduction to `Mojo::DOM` check out [`Mojocast Episode 5`](http://mojocasts.com/e5).